# AutoGPT runtime error - unable to import main

Tags: python, autogpt

I am unable to run the `main.py`, I get the following error:

```
X:\Auto-GPT>python main.py --speak
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Auto-GPT\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from autogpt import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'autogpt' (X:\Auto-GPT\autogpt\__init__.py)
```

How can I resolve it?

I have uninstalled and installed `autogpt`, but this issue persists.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled in an attempt to resolve but that dint work. I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to use python -m autogpt, the other way doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).